# PC's cant resolve the servers name

Tags: domain-name-system, ping, nslookup

we've recently upgraded our server and we've been having an issue where the computers can't find the server without me mapping it's IP in the hosts file.

They can find it when I fully qualify it with the domain name, but without it, theyre unable to. I've searched/played with the DNS settings but can't find anything to help resolve this.

```
ping ARTDC01 - fails
ping ARTDC01.art.local - works
NSLOOKUP - ARTDC01 - fails
```

I ran some ping's and nslookups to display the issue.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Craig>ping artdc01
Ping request could not find host artdc01. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\Craig>ping artdc01.art.local

Pinging artdc01.art.local [192.168.10.14] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.10.14: bytes=32 time=119ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.10.14: bytes=32 time=110ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.10.14: bytes=32 time=188ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.10.14: bytes=32 time=112ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.10.14:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 110ms, Maximum = 188ms, Average = 132ms

C:\Users\Craig>nslookup
Default Server:  artdc01.art.local
Address:  192.168.10.14

> artdc01
Server:  artdc01.art.local
Address:  192.168.10.14

*** artdc01.art.local can't find artc01.art.local: Non-existent domain
> artdc01.art.local
Server:  artdc01.art.local
Address:  192.168.10.14

Name:    artdc01.art.local
Address:  192.168.10.14
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the Server/DNS setup? I.E. What DNS server are you using? If it's server based, what is the server? Etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using HOSTS file, here's some things I would try:

1. On the server, disable all but 1 network card and ipconfig/ flushdns
2. Assign static IP to each workstation (including server)
3. Stop the "DNS Client" Windows service and try again.
4. Disable Anti-Virus.  I had Symantec Endpoint smart firewall that did this.
5. Enable Network discovery on the server

This normally happens to me when I work with servers with multiple network cards.

Comment: Okay, so turns out the server installation guys had disabled all the services/settings for the server to be discoverable over the network. No idea why... Thanks for the tip! Never would have thought to check network discovery on a server.